# How to learn the maximum power usage of my laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply

[image: system specs]

Other people already asked this question, and were referred to internet tools to calculate maximum power usage, but I don't know how to get the information it wanted. For example, it wanted to know how many RAM components I had and how much RAM each one had. I only know that I have 16GBs of RAM, as far as I know that could be 4 4GB cards, or two 8 GB cards, or 137,438,953,472 cards, one per bit, IDK jack. My CPU is Intel Core i5-4210H but I can't find it on any of the web calculators. They ask about my GPU, which I was quite certain was by Nvida, yet when I run DXDIAG, all it says is Intel Graphics 4600. but the web calculators, only have AMD/Nvida options.

The thing is, I have a laptop, which has a battery. Is there really no way to measure how much power my computer uses with out purchasing a gizmo? It seems to me like a no brainer that something like that would be built into a laptop, especially one as powerful as mine. (IDK how powerful it is, but it can play Fallout 4 on high settings with a realistic ENB mod...I've only encountered a couple games that I need to lower the settings on)

Maybe this isn't relevant, but the reason I want to know is because I was thinking about building a tiny house, and I want to invest in a solar panel that will keep my laptop charged even while I'm playing demanding vidya.

Comment: Check your battery capacity, in Wh (Watt-hours) -- some tools can read this, it is also printed on a sticker on the battery.  Charge the battery fully, unplug from wall, see how long it takes to discharge.  Divide capacity by runtime to get average usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) program to get internals of your laptop on Windows.
Use `dmidecode` on Unix based systems for the same things.

You can track battery status by using [BatteryInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) (BTW, it will show wearing level too), but to measure real consumed power it would be probably the best idea to get in any homedepot store device that calls "Kill-A-Watt" (isn't expensive)

As about tiny house, ghm... cheapest and fastest solution I think would be http://www.containerhomeplans.org/

Answer (score 0):

Online power usage calculators are by no means precise, they can give you a reasonable estimate at best. If by mistake you specify 2 RAM modules when in fact you have one, I would expect the resulting discrepancy be rather small compared to the discrepancy between the estimation and the *actual* power consumption that you could measure.

Another point: whatever power consumption estimate you'll get has to be checked for taking the efficiency of your laptop's power supply into account, and divided by the said efficiency if it doesn't.

A simple way to be sure your laptop will be able to work *and* charge from the solar panel is to get a panel which provides at least **the power specified on your laptop's power supply**. About half of it should be enough to *keep* the laptop charged while being used. Anything more precise than that would require actual measurements.